# Minimum Argument Difference to Make the Lower Bound > the Upper Bound

Tags: functions, prime-numbers, approximation, inverse, lambert-w

Assume $g$ is a function that grows asymptotically as 
$$
g(n) \in\frac n {log(n)} + O(\sqrt n),\,n \in \Bbb N\tag1
$$
I wish to find $h(n)$ such that
$$
g(n) \le g(n+h(n)).
$$
i.e. Given the bounds
$$
\begin{align}
u(n)=\frac n {log(n)} + \sqrt{n} \tag 2 \\
l(n)=\frac n {log(n)} - \sqrt{n} \tag 3
\end{align}
$$
what $h(n)$ would give
$$
u(n)\le l(n+h(n)) \tag 4
$$
Since $h(n)$ would simply be the difference of the inverse functions of $(2)$ and $(3)$, my approach so far has been to look for these. The inverse of $f(n)=n/log(n)$ is given by
$$
f^{-1}(n)=e^{-W(-1/n)} \tag 5
$$
which has the multivalued Lambert W function, where the principal branch for reals stops at $e$. The analytic continuation is
$$
f^{-1}(n) = n \log(n \log(n \log(...\,\,,\,\, n>e \tag 6
$$ 
but I haven't found a way to express the inverse of the bounding functions. Maybe I need a taylor series or some integral to approximate these?

---

Proof of $(6)$

The inverse of $y = {x / log(x)}$ is
$$
x = {y / log(y)}.\tag7
$$
Assume $(7)$ can be equated to
$$
y=x\,log(x\,log(x\,log(x\,...\tag8
$$
The expression inside the first log function is $y$, so we have
$$
y=x\,log(y).\tag9
$$
Dividing through by $log (y)$ confirms the original assumption (for $x>e$). $(8)$ returns the upper branch value (the area of interest), whereas $(5)$ returns only the principal value.

---

**Addendum**
Apparently, $(1)$ is weaker than I intended. How could it be made stronger, such that $(2)$ and $(3)$ are strict bounds? My guess is that substituting $O()$ with something like
$$
o(x^{\frac 1 2 - \epsilon})\tag{10}
$$
would eliminate the implied constant of $O()$, and reflect my intention that
$$
\forall n \in \Bbb N, l(n) < g(n) < u(n)\tag{11}
$$
and $(4)$ holds such that
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac {l(n+h(n))}{u(n)} \to 1^+.\tag{12}
$$

Comment: Could you clarify what your question is?  It's unlikely that $(1)$ and $(3)$ have closed-form representations for their inverses, so what are you looking to know about them?

Comment: @AntonioVargas Done. (1) and (3) are now (2) and (3). Any form or derivation that leads to an expression for h(n) will do.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that the optimal choice of $h(n)$ depends on the constant implicit in the $O(\sqrt{n})$ term, so redefine

$$
u(n) = \frac{n}{\log n} + c\sqrt{n}
$$

and

$$
l(n) = \frac{n}{\log n} - c\sqrt{n},
$$

where $c > 0$ is fixed.  Assuming $h = o(n)$, solving the equation

$$
u(n) = l(n+h)
$$

asymptotically for $h$ yields

$$
h(n) \sim 2c\sqrt{n}\log n. \tag{1}
$$

Further, it's possible to show that

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} u(n) - l(n+2c\sqrt{n}\log n) = \infty \tag{2}
$$

and that, for any $\epsilon > 0$,

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} u(n) - l(n+(2+\epsilon)c\sqrt{n}\log n) = -\infty. \tag{3}
$$

Consequently, if

$$
l(n) \leq g(n) \leq u(n)
$$

for $n$ large enough then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $n_0(\epsilon)$ such that

$$
g(n) \leq g(n+(2+\epsilon)c\sqrt{n}\log n) \tag{4}
$$

for $n \geq n_0(\epsilon)$.

(Note that we cannot take $\epsilon = 0$ in general, since any function $g(n)$ which oscillates between $l(n)$ and $u(n)$ will satisfy

$$
g(n) > g(n+2c\sqrt{n}\log n)
$$

infinitely often.  For a concrete example, take $g(n) = n/\log n + c\sqrt{n}\sin n$.)

---

**Proof of $(1)$.**

If we expand

$$
\begin{align}
l(n+h) &= \frac{n+h}{\log(n+h)} - c\sqrt{n+h} \\
&= \frac{n+h}{\log n + \log(1 + h/n)} - c\sqrt{n+h} \\
&= \frac{n+h}{\log n} \frac{1}{1 + \frac{\log(1+h/n)}{\log n}} - c\sqrt{n}\sqrt{1+h/n} \\
&= \frac{n+h}{\log n} \left[1 + O\left(\frac{h}{n\log n}\right)\right] - c\sqrt{n} \left[1 + O\left(\frac{h}{n}\right)\right] \\
&= \frac{n+h}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{h}{(\log n)^2}\right) - c\sqrt{n} + O\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}\right),
\end{align}
$$

then the equation $l(n+h) - u(n) = 0$ becomes

$$
\frac{h}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{h}{(\log n)^2}\right) - 2c\sqrt{n} + O\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}\right) = 0. \tag{5}
$$

A dominant balance is achieved if

$$
\frac{h}{\log n} \asymp 2c\sqrt{n},
$$

so it follows that $h \sim 2c\sqrt{n} \log n$.

---

**Proof of $(2)$ and $(3)$.**

We know from $(5)$ that, for $h = o(n)$,

$$
u(n) - l(n+h) = 2c\sqrt{n} - \frac{h}{\log n} + O\left(\frac{h}{(\log n)^2}\right) + O\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}\right).
$$

By taking $h = (2+\varepsilon)c\sqrt{n}\log n$ with $\epsilon > 0$ we see that

$$
u(n) - l(n+h) \sim -\epsilon c \sqrt{n} \to -\infty,
$$

which proves $(3)$.

Proving $(2)$ is only slightly more difficult; we need to expand the first term of $l(n+h)$ to one more order.  I'll omit the calculations here and just state the result that, for $h = o(n)$,

$$
u(n) - l(n+h) = 2c\sqrt{n} - \frac{h}{\log n} + \frac{h}{(\log n)^2} +  O\left(\frac{h^2}{n(\log n)^2}\right) + O\left(\frac{h}{\sqrt{n}}\right).
$$

By taking $h = 2c\sqrt{n}\log n$ we see that

$$
u(n) - l(n+h) \sim \frac{2c\sqrt{n}}{\log n} \to \infty,
$$

which proves $(2)$.

Comment: Can the result from your omitted proof of (2) be expanded further to an infinite series of higher orders? If my (1) was stronger, such that (2) an (3) were strict boundaries

Comment: Yes, it should be possible to obtain higher order terms for $h(n)$ provided higher order terms for $g$ are known.

Comment: Your analysis is excellent, so I provided a clarifying addendum rather than amend my original question.